# How much is "half" in Scotland

Tags: uk, food-and-drink

In a bar in Scotland, two sizes are listed for the beer - pint and half. I assume that half is half pint, however for all beers the price for "half" doubled is less then the price for a pint (say pint is 5.50, while half is 2.30). So it does not make sense to me. What does half mean in this context? Is it half pint? If so, what is the reason why two halfs cost less than a whole pint? Is this something standard here?
[image: menu image]

Comment: I say this as an expert - having drunk beers in Scotland for almost half a century: It is not standard - that bar is doing something very weird with their pricing.

Comment: Marketing technique, ordering halves makes you sit longer perhaps, which makes you hungry so you order food, and feeling the price is less you might end up ordering 3 halves instead of one pint.

Comment: Or they had drunk to many halves before editing the prices :-)

Comment: So order "two halves in a pint glass".

Comment: Most likely this is an error on the menu.

Comment: A marketing ploy to encourage people to try new ales? https://harpers.co.uk/news/fullstory.php/aid/17955/_Halves_more_popular_than_pints_for_beer__-_nbsp;Camra_survey.html Or a printing error reversing £3.20 to £2.30?

Comment: Or a marketing ploy to reach more people by people discussing their pricing policy? I most probably would never heard about the place.

Comment: Questions like these confuse me. The correct answer is easy enough to come by.... ASK them. It's still a useful and interesting question, and once you determine the answer by asking the proprietors, answer it yourself.

Comment: My sister came to visit me in Bristol in 1973. We went to a pub and I asked for two pints of cider. The barman said 'The boss says we can't serve pints of cider to ladies'. Even then that was a bit ridiculous. I said 'Really? We'll just go somewhere else'. The barman looked around and muttered 'just buy two halves'.

Comment: @CGCampbell well if the answer is "actually you are right, you should pay more" the outcome is somewhat undesirable

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As [this other answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/176005/1972) correctly says, the "Half" means indeed half pint.

As for the weird pricing, they changed the menu, and got some mistakes while doing it.

[This](https://resdiary.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/uk/14952/menus/alacarte/Dulse%20%20Brose%20Menu%20June%202021.pdf) is the previous menu, with "correct" prices:

[image: screenshot of the menu]

So they raised the price of all draft beers, and forgot to raise it for the half pints as well.

Comment: +1 Nice sleuthing.

Comment: Lol. The internet is amazing. Follow up on law SE: Is that menu a binding offer in the jurisdiction of Scotland?

Comment: @Peter [already asked](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8597/can-a-restaurant-or-retailer-be-held-to-posted-prices)! Well, for USA, but still... ;)

Comment: @JackAidley yeah, here in Israel anyone can add one word to legal document (טל"ח) and that would dismiss any legal charges in case of honest mistake. Probably same in other places.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica -  Menus and advertisements are "invitations to treat" in UK law (all jurisdictions). There is no legal obligation on the merchant to honour a price.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, but they need to actually _tell_ the price up front anyway, right? I mean, if I went there, ordered a half, they poured it in a glass and told me a different price than the one in the menu, I might be a bit cross. Or is it just their problem at that point to deal with the wasted half-pint if I now refused the price?

Comment: @ilkkachu 1. Main legal requirements - The prices of food and drink, which are sold for consumption on business premises or at takeaways, should be displayed so that consumers can see them before they decide to buy. The price is material information key to any purchasing decision so it must not be misleading, Typically businesses achieve compliance by having a price list displayed on a list or on bar menus etc. which can be seen or referred to before orders are placed. If there is a printing error then a mistaken price does not bind the pub.

Comment: @ilkkachu - Pub staff are legally allowed to order you to leave and ban you from returning, and would be very likely to do this if you behaved in a vexatious manner, like making them waste a drink over 45p.

Comment: A flexible and decent publican might honour the printed half-pint prices once per customer, advising them that there had been a printing error, and promptly re-print the menus. Disciplining the staff member who had done the printing, and/or the one who should have checked it, are also possible.

Comment: I agree with @Michael and would like to add, it's really case-by-case, and depends who runs the company. While not obliged to honor the wrong price, so do it even when it costs them millions, e.g. remember a case where flight company had price of $1 on their website for a flight that should cost, well, much more, and they did honor it, and thus gained lots of respect. (Thinking about it now, it might have been staged, i.e. the $1 was not a mistake as they said, but rather smart marketing.)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, yeah, that's kinda the point there, the price must be visible but if there's a printing error the visible price doesn't bind the pub. But it might bind the customer on threat of a ban. That doesn't sound too fair to me.

Comment: @ilkkachu these days, customer can publish such thing on their Facebook or Twitter, if it gets enough attention, restaurant might go bankrupt as result.

Comment: @ilkkachu A friendly pub that wants to attract tourists and does not want negative reviews on social media. Trip Advisor, etc, is not going to ban a customer, but at the same time truculent customers are not liked either.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, after reading these discussions, I'm getting the impression that UK laws and customs are actually rather hostile towards customers. Social media doesn't help there. That 45 p isn't much of an issue (and probably shouldn't be for the pub either, they could just suck it up and fix their mistake just the same as the customer could), but the principle of being allowed to tell a customer "sorry, we made a mistake and you have to pay for it" is a problem.

Comment: @ilkkachu - they have the same concept in US law as well.

Answer (score 29):

A "half" is indeed a half pint. The amount is regulated by law and can't be less.

I'm as baffled as you are by the pricing policy. It may be a mistake, or it may be intended to encourage people to drink less, or maybe try more of their varieties of beers. Or it may be relying on the traditional Scottish attitude that "half pints are for wusses" to never have to serve one. ( That last was a joke, don't call me out on it.)

Comment: In the example, they are NOT charging more for the half, they even charge less, hence the question.

Comment: Yes indeed charging me more for two halves than the whole pint would make sense and is what I've seen everywhere else. That is what gets me confused

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect my confusion.

Comment: A pint is basically the "Planck volume" in many counties. It's impossible to measure beer in anything smaller.

Comment: @EricDuminil, In France the standard size (the most ordered, or even the one you'd get if you just ask for "a beer please") is the "_Demi_", which contains 25cl. But you can also easily order a "_Gallopin_" which will get you a 12.5cl glass of beer.

Comment: @Hoki: Indeed, but France seems to be an exception. That's also why I wrote "many countries" and not all. In Germany/Ireland/Scotlan/..., for example, you'd get a pint when you order a beer. *Demis* are already expensive enough in Paris, you might want to think twice before ordering a pint there.

Comment: @EricDuminil 0.5 L is less than an imperial pint so getting less is the default in Germany and getting exactly that is nearly impossible. Joke aside, in practice, most establishments do have smaller options there too, at least for draught beer.

Comment: @Relaxed: Thanks for the info. I thought a UK pint was 473 ml (which apparently is a "liquid pint" and not an "imperial pint").

Comment: @EricDuminil That's a US unit, not the volume of a standard glass in the UK or Ireland.

Answer (score -3):

Usually anyone asking for a pint and a half is asking for a pint and a spirit - the measure of spirit is the 'half'. It's a colloquialism.  Older gents (usually always gents) asked for 'a hauf and a hauf pint' back in the day - lack of spare cash would be the reason.

Comment: While this is an explanation about the use of 'half' in the UK, it does not explain the 'half' in the question. (I did not down vote but that might be the reason someone did.)

Comment: That's a very unusual use of "half". In the twenty years I spend drinking in Britain I never encountered it.